# Snapping geometries to a layer without distortion

Tags: snapping

I am looking for a plugin / script to snap a polygon layer (A) to a linestring layer (B), the example datasets in image 1.

I have tried the 'Snap geometries to layer' tool in QGIS 3.4.

This snaps the nodes within a set distance, but doesn't 'move' the shape, example in image 2.
It results in the width and shape of the polygon layer being distorted.

I would like the shape to be 'moved' towards the linestring layer.
The nearest node ONLY on the polygon layer snapped to the nearest point on the linestring layer, the rest of the feature should be moved with it.
Example in image 3.
Each feature should be moved separately. The dimensions of each feature should not be changed, only the coordinates.

The projection will be EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid - Projected, and the format can be ESRI shapefile or geojson.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]